# Managing images (upload, description and order) - webmatrix/razor

Tags: sql, image, razor, webmatrix

i am creating a site where users will upload pictures of their houses. I'm guessing the best way to achieve this, would to have a database table, and when users upload their photo's, it saves the destination and the href in the database right?

What if uses wanted to change around the order of how the photo's appear, what would be the best way to achieve this, is there an API for it, or some pre-written code?

Thanks, Gavin

Comment: Did you know that you could do this without actually saving the image files? I achieved this saving the binary data in an 'image' data-type field in SQL Server CE

Answer (score 1):

You could have a table in your database that will store the preferred order of images for each user. It would contain the user id, image id and order columns. Or if image is associated to a user record, you could simply add an order column to the users table.

Comment: This was exactly what i was thinking, but i imagine it would be quite hard to write something that posts the order back to the database each time, don't you think? what would you suggest for changing the order, Jquery? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sure the best way to achieve this would be a database.  With a database you can build a very nice back end where the users can manage their profile.  There are some pre-written asp.net projects that allow you to achieve simple things like this such as [dot-net nuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

Comment: i want to design it with scalability in mind. If the website takes off like i hope it will, then storing them in a database wont be sustainable.

Comment: Database can always be sustainable.  You just have to know how to use it. For example you would do things like, achieve the jquery client side event, then update database through ajax at the end.  This is very lightweight using json.  If you are really concerned with bandwidth you could use Azure or S3.